# Oracle select query error inside procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

I'm getting error while I'm running `select` query inside procedure. Error print as follow:

> [Error] PLS-00428 (24: 9): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACK_EMP
IS
    PROCEDURE find_employee(
        P_ID NUMBER,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        IF P_ID IS NULL THEN
            SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = P_ID
        ELSE
            P_ERR := 'An error occured on database!!';
        END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            P_ERR := SQLERRM;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: In PL/SQL when you are doing any SELECT, you need to specify in which variable to store select result with INTO clause: `SELECT 1 INTO v_val FROM DUAL`. What you're trying to achieve with this procedure?

Comment: Thanks for aid, i am careless to much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACK_EMP
IS
    PROCEDURE find_employee(
        P_ID NUMBER,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2,
        V_VAL OUT VARCHAR
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        IF P_ID IS NULL THEN
            SELECT FIRTSNAME ||' '||LASTNAME INTO V_VAL FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = P_ID
        ELSE
            P_ERR := 'An error occured on database!!';
        END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            P_ERR := SQLERRM;
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a rowtype.  Also I think you meant to say "IF P_ID IS ***NOT*** NULL THEN..." because if it is null then your select will never work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACK_EMP
IS
    PROCEDURE find_employee(
        P_ID NUMBER,
        P_ERR OUT VARCHAR2
    )
    IS
    empRec employee%rowtype; /* ADD THIS LINE */
    BEGIN
        IF P_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
            SELECT * into empRec FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = P_ID;
            --now you can reference the columns like this: empRec.id
        ELSE
            P_ERR := 'An error occured on database!!';
        END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            P_ERR := SQLERRM;
    END;
END;
```